# Raid 1 Hard disk failure - Windows 2012 on HP proliant N54L

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, hp-proliant

We have a domain controller setup on Windows 2012 Standard (not R2).

We had two raided hard disks. One has failed.

This is on a proliant N54L server.

Windows 2012 refuses to boot on Raid 1, regardless of whether we remove the failed disk or swap the disks between ports.

What are our options to get the server up and running?

Comment: Sounds like you should restore from backups.  You **do** have backups, don't you?  RAID is not a backup.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to boot ?

Comment: Software or hardware RAID?

Comment: yeeeeeaaahhh  The N54Ls hardware raid is um...well... not very fantastic.  Ran into the same problem with it and despite the fact it should work, when I replaced the failed drive, the server decided to mash up the new drive and the existing drive in the RAID1 array.  It also refused to allow the 2nd drive in the array to boot.  You could try swapping the slot the drive is in with the primary and see if it will boot, but that netted me no luck either.  In other words, like HopelessN00b said, you will probably need backups.  Good luck!